# Highcharts: a stacked column for every series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.
I want a column for every data series. With all values in this series stacked.

**Example** (with food):
1st column: Fruits - with all Fruits in one stacked column
2nd column: Vegetables- with all Vegetables in one stacked column
and so on...

In all examples I found, the series' spans over all columns.

I've found some workarounds:

```
series: [{
    data: [['Apple',55]]
},{
    data: [['Banana',99]]
},{
    data: [null,['Cucumber',22]]
},{
    data: [null,['Potato',88]]
},{
    data: [null,null,['Walnut',33]]
},{
    data: [null,null,['Hazelnut',111]]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzuqr81c/6/

```
series: [{
    data: [{x:0,y:30,name:'Apple'},{x:0,y:30,name:'Banana'}],
    stacking: true
},{
    data: [{x:1,y:15,name:'Cucumber'},{x:1,y:55,name:'Potato'}],
    stacking: true
},{
    data: [{x:2,y:35,name:'Walnut'},{x:2,y:20,name:'Hazelnut'}],
    stacking: true
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bkt6ju5/5/

I'm fine with the results, but this can't be the intended way, right?

Comment: I fairly confident that what you have posted is the intended way.

Comment: @ewolden: thanks. this will be quite finicky to get a large data set in this format :(